# electromagnetic energy harvesting LTspice simulation problem

Tags: resistance, boost, inductance, electromagnetic, energy-harvesting

In my project I need to use electromagnetic energy harvesting that provides below 1V. Rectification and voltage level boosting are required to meet the power supply requirements of typical electronic circuits.

In the paper *Ultralow Power, Fully Autonomous Boost Rectifier for Electromagnetic Energy Harvesters,* the author used a 5.35mH inductance coil with a coil resistance of 80 ohm. The problem is when I do the simulation in LTspice the output converter are corrected  when I delete the 80 ohm coil resistance. I don't know what the problem is, exactly. What is the importance of this resistance?

The signals (PWM1 and PWM2) that commands the two MOSFETs and the schematic circuit in the figures below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not everyone has acess to that paper, but either you're not showing the whole schematic, or those gates are floating. Also, if it's about energy harvesting, a stiff 1 V source that can deliver kA or more might not be the best approximation for your input -- but then I can't see that paper.

Comment: Are you sure the switching frequency is **23**768, not **32**768? It's a minor thing, but you're talking about a boost rectifier (converter), and I only see an active rectifier. And even this is modelled with a 0.5 Vpk sine at the input, but the diodes alone will ned at least some 0.4 V for the threshold, if not more since this is low current. Again, without seeing the paper or excerpts from it, all the pictures are showing is your interpretation of it. So I'd guess that it's a sort of a dual boost converter, as opposed to a rectifier, working directly from the energy harvester.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen what is the importance of the coil resistance ?because in the simulation it  decrease the curent so it is very diffucult to charge the capactance

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen what's mean 0.5Vpk

Answer (score 1):

Finally I saw your PWM signals, they are weird. The signals interrupt for some milliseconds, IMHO they should not pause. I would expect something like [practical graph of PWM1 and PWM2 signals as Q and Q'](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/uploads/articles/complementary_pmw_figure_6_dead-time_signals.jpg).
Your schematic is somehow not correct/confusing. IMHO it does not fit the PWM1 and PWM2 signals.
U1 is not an oscillator, U2 yes - but why V2 is needed? Starting the oscillation in simulation not possible - because no noise source as in reality?
U1's output should oscillate, then your picture of PWM1 and PWM2 makes sense, (despite not correct iMHO). But how? Is V4 an AC source? I do not see, why V4 has to oscillate.
U1 looks more like a level shifter.
Oh and the [LT1018](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/10178ff.pdf) is a comparator - where are its pull up resistors at the output of U1? Even if the datasheet states in DESCRIPTION of page 1 that is has a pull-up current source internally, due to V9, that output of U1 can be 0 or 1.5 V max! This is to low for practical logic devices - but A2 and A3 handle this? As well as A1?
The other pins of the AND are pulled to 15 V due to V6 and U1 output!?

And the A2 and A3 are NANDs, and some of its inputs are connected to ground, so its output should always stay high/1! **So your simulation schematic does not fit the picture of PWM1 and PWM2 signals! Please correct!**

First I would fix the creation of the PWM1 and PWM2 signals, that they look like Q and Q' in [this graph](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/uploads/articles/complementary_pmw_figure_6_dead-time_signals.jpg), so check if POS and NEG signal is a constant square wave without breaks.
Then level shift them properly to 15 V to 0 V square signals.

Then (optionally) add the dead time, see an idea [here], that PWM! and PWM2 have a dead time in between of e. g. 1us (https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-dead-time-generator_fig5_335681607). In your low power application it won't harm really the MOSFETs, but it could dampen the magnetic field in reality?

As @aconcernedcitizen mentionned, the diodes consume a lot of the power. But because the [BAT52](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/308/1/BAT54S_D-2310217.pdf) are Shottky diodes, they have only 0.24 V drop at 0.1 mA. So it could work, if the coil delivers more than e. g. 1 Vp.
And it would not be possible to detect the polarity of voltage across L1 and switch a full bridge with 4 MOSFETs in 0 ns. Especially if the coil picks up high frequency electromagnetical field.

I would model the coil as a voltage source with 80 Ohm, remove the 5.35 mH! The coil *is* the voltage source - then its inductivity is like inexistent.
As an example why the inductivity is irrelevant here: a regular power transformator's output will be modelled as e. g. 12 VAC source (mostly not even with an inner resistance), the 12 VAC coil in the transformator picks up the electromagnetic field inside the transformator's core - it's inductivity does not matter practically at all in that case!

But your C1 is IMHO huge with 11.5 mF! It will use seconds to load fully with 80 Ohm in L1! I would use e. g. 1 uF to start with.

Please add the document you mentionned - as @aconcernedcitizen mentionned.  And  The [FDS6574A](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fds6574a-d.pdf) has not 0 ns switching on and off time.